# The internal implementation of R's dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to build a data processing program. Currently I use a double matrix to represent the data table, each row is an instance, each column represents a feature. I also have an extra vector as the target value for each instance, it is of double type for regression, it is of integer for classification.

I want to make it more general. I am wondering what kind of structure R uses to store a dataset, i.e. the internal implementation in R.

Comment: What do you mean by "the internal implementation in R"?  Are you asking about the linear algebra library that's used?

Comment: @Shane, R's dataset not the entire R.

Comment: There is no such thing as an R "dataset". Are you asking about any representation of data in R? There are many different data structures, so you need to be more specific.

Comment: @Shane. Yes. I think dataframe is one of them. However dataframe is too dynamic, thus less efficient. What are the others?

Comment: I still think that your question is too vague.  Until you clarify what you mean, you won't likely get a satisfactory answer.  For instance, in what sense is a data frame "too dynamic"?  Maybe provide some sample data so people can advise you on the right data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you inspect the [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html) package, you can learn something about how data structures are represented (and can be accessed).

Comment: What does this question have to do with python?

Comment: Nothing. Maybe I did not understand the question poster right.

Answer (score 1):

The internal data structures are `data.frame', a detailed introduction to the data frame can be found here.

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Data-frames